# fork statement in toy language java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to implement the fork statement in my toy language using the rule:

```
ExeStack1={fork(Stmt1) | Stmt2|Stmt3|....}
SymTable1,
Heap1,
Out1,
id1
==>
ExeStack2={Stmt2 | Stmt3|.....}
SymTable2=SymTable1
Heap2 = Heap1
Out2 = Out1
id2=id1
and a new PrgSate is created with the following data structures:
ExeStack3=Stmt1
SymTable3=clone(SymTable1)
Heap3=Heap1,
Out3=Out1
id3= id1*10 in order to be unique
```

Having this notes: the new PrgState is returned by the execute method. As you can see above, when a fork statement is on top of the ExeStack a new PrgState (thread) is generated having as ExeStack the argument of the fork, as SymTable a clone of the parent PrgState (parent thread) SymTable, as Heap a reference to the parent PrgState (parent thread) Heap and as Out a reference to the parent PrgState (parent thread) Out. Please note that Heap and Out are shared by all PrgStates. The SymTable of the new thread is a clone (or a new copy) and is
not shared with the parent thread. 
I implemented something like this:

```
  public class ForkStmt implements IStmt,Serializable{
  IStmt stmt;
  public ForkStmt(IStmt st){
      stmt= st;
  }
  public IStmt getStmt(){
      return stmt;
  }
  public String toString(){
      return "fork(" + stmt + ")";
  }
  public PrgState execute(PrgState prg){

      IStack<IStmt> a =prg.getStk();
      a = (IStack<IStmt>)stmt;
      Id<Object,Integer> dictRef = prg.getDict();

      IHeap<Integer,Integer> h = prg.getHeap();
      IList<Object> l = prg.getList();
      PrgState forkPrg = new PrgState(a,dictRef,l,h);
    return forkPrg;

  }
```

}

It is good implemented? Thank you.

Comment: Have you run some tests to see if it works?

Comment: Does it work? Do you have a problem with it?

Comment: Well, my project runs but it gives me some exception from another part of this project and how that part is connected with this ForkStmt I was sure that something is wrong with this implementation.

Comment: Please post all of the error outut you are getting, is it impossible to diagnose the problem without seeing this! Please add it to your question.